# Changing colour modes Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, rgb

I'm finalising a logo in illustrator, saving out different file types to deliver to the client. So I want to give an RGB and CMYK version. It was originally designed on an RGB artboard. Is converting it to CMYK just as simple as file> document colormode> CMYK ?

It feels like i'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct. I don't know of any other way to convert document color mode.

Here is a reference link

[Change color mode in illustrator](http://blog.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/converting-rgb-to-cmyk-in-illustrator_53/)